# Why my android send email intent method isn't work

Tags: java, android, android-intent, google-maps-android-api-2

Hi all I'm a newbie for android programmer.
I have build send email intent method with status of GPS. I have a one button if user click this button i have if function to check status of GPS. and send email but send email by intent is not work and in LogCat has show this error

```
    07-16 16:23:30.161: E/AndroidRuntime(28567): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-16 16:23:30.161: E/AndroidRuntime(28567): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
07-16 16:23:30.161: E/AndroidRuntime(28567):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3735)
07-16 16:23:30.161: E/AndroidRuntime(28567):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4354)
07-16 16:23:30.161: E/AndroidRuntime(28567):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17961)
07-16 16:23:30.161: E/AndroidRuntime(28567):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-16 16:23:30.161: E/AndroidRuntime(28567):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-16 16:23:30.161: E/AndroidRuntime(28567):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-16 16:23:30.161: E/AndroidRuntime(28567):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5328)
07-16 16:23:30.161: E/AndroidRuntime(28567):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-16 16:23:30.161: E/AndroidRuntime(28567):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-16 16:23:30.161: E/AndroidRuntime(28567):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
07-16 16:23:30.161: E/AndroidRuntime(28567):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
07-16 16:23:30.161: E/AndroidRuntime(28567):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-16 16:23:30.161: E/AndroidRuntime(28567): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-16 16:23:30.161: E/AndroidRuntime(28567):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-16 16:23:30.161: E/AndroidRuntime(28567):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-16 16:23:30.161: E/AndroidRuntime(28567):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3730)
07-16 16:23:30.161: E/AndroidRuntime(28567):    ... 11 more
07-16 16:23:30.161: E/AndroidRuntime(28567): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Plain text must be supplied if HTML text is supplied
07-16 16:23:30.161: E/AndroidRuntime(28567):    at android.content.ClipData$Item.<init>(ClipData.java:252)
07-16 16:23:30.161: E/AndroidRuntime(28567):    at android.content.Intent.migrateExtraStreamToClipData(Intent.java:7253)
07-16 16:23:30.161: E/AndroidRuntime(28567):    at android.content.Intent.migrateExtraStreamToClipData(Intent.java:7234)
07-16 16:23:30.161: E/AndroidRuntime(28567):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1428)
07-16 16:23:30.161: E/AndroidRuntime(28567):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3430)
07-16 16:23:30.161: E/AndroidRuntime(28567):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3391)
07-16 16:23:30.161: E/AndroidRuntime(28567):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:817)
07-16 16:23:30.161: E/AndroidRuntime(28567):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3626)
07-16 16:23:30.161: E/AndroidRuntime(28567):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3594)
07-16 16:23:30.161: E/AndroidRuntime(28567):    at com.mpa.emvi.HomeActivity.sendEmail(HomeActivity.java:100)
07-16 16:23:30.161: E/AndroidRuntime(28567):    ... 14 more
```

OK In my HomActivityClass is

```
    package com.mpa.emvi;

import com.mpa.emvi.R;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class HomeActivity extends FragmentActivity 
 implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {


    private LocationManager mLocationManager;
    boolean statusOfGPS;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private LocationClient mLocationClient;
    private String DescribText = new String();

    private static final String TAG = "MyGPS_status";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);        
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
        setUpLocationClientIfNeeded();
        mLocationClient.connect();
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                 mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    }

    private void setUpLocationClientIfNeeded() {
        if (mLocationClient == null) {
          mLocationClient = new LocationClient(
              getApplicationContext(),
              this,  // ConnectionCallbacks
              this); // OnConnectionFailedListener
        }
     }

    public void sendEmail(View view){
        statusOfGPS = mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        if (mLocationClient != null && mLocationClient.isConnected() && statusOfGPS == true) {
            DescribText = "This is My Emergency Location on GPS " +
                    "<a href='https://maps.google.com/maps?q='"+mLocationClient.getLastLocation().getLatitude()+"','"+mLocationClient.getLastLocation().getLongitude()+"'&ll='"+mLocationClient.getLastLocation().getLatitude()+"','"+mLocationClient.getLastLocation().getLongitude()+"'&z=17'>click here</a>";

            i.setType("text/html");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"suphawut@mpatmail.com"});
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Emergency Location");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_HTML_TEXT   , DescribText);
            try {
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

         Log.d(TAG, "gps =" + statusOfGPS);
        }else{
            DescribText = "This is My Emergency Location on INTERNET" +
                    " <a href='https://maps.google.com/maps?q='"+mLocationClient.getLastLocation().getLatitude()+"','"+mLocationClient.getLastLocation().getLongitude()+"'&ll='"+mLocationClient.getLastLocation().getLatitude()+"','"+mLocationClient.getLastLocation().getLongitude()+"'&z=17'>click here</a>";

            i.setType("text/html");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"suphawut@mpatmail.com"});
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Emergency Location");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_HTML_TEXT   , DescribText);
            try {
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

          Log.d(TAG, "gps =" + statusOfGPS);                 
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

    }

    /**
     * Callback called when disconnected from GCore. Implementation of {@link ConnectionCallbacks}.
     */
    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
      // Do nothing
    }

    /**
     * Implementation of {@link OnConnectionFailedListener}.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
      // Do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    public void onProviderEnable(String provider){

    }
}
```

The send email by intent is in sendEmail method why this work?

P.S. my English skill is poor and Thank for any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts("mailto","suphawut@mpatmail.com", null));
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Emergency Location");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,Html.fromHtml(DescribText));
```

Comment: but, what about if I want to send a HTML email ?